# reCaptcha does not display on modal window(colorbox) webform

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms, captcha

I have a webform that I want to add a reCaptcha to. So far I've done everything properly, the webform will display a recaptcha box below the form when viewing the node form. I have a modal window webform (thats similar to an opt-in form), that uses ajax to grab the specific webform and display it as a block in the window. Now the issue is that the reCaptcha does not display below the form.

I've tried replacing the recaptcha with a math challenge captcha, and it would display properly on both the webform and modal window.

The good news is that the ajax webform shows an instance of the captcha when you look at the html.

```
<div class="captcha"><input type="hidden" name="captcha_sid" value="561">
<input type="hidden" name="captcha_token" value="4bbbf337ec22df5fe3befde6f601601d">
<input type="hidden" name="captcha_response" value="Google no captcha">

//g-recaptcha is where the captcha is supposed to be rendered, however it is empty
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld1XSMUAAAAABJRpsnwwzlV7_yceyWERRWnCYgc" data-theme="light" data-type="image"></div></div>
```

I've been stuck on this issue for almost a week. Is there suggestions or approach that I should take?

Comment: Is it doing this through vanilla jQuery or through a callback with AjaxCommands ?

Comment: I believe it is using ajaxCommands make callbacks. I'm using the colorbox-node module which seems like it is using Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, there was a patch on issue's forum on the Module page.

## 71 @ https://www.drupal.org/node/2493183